# Get one view holder reference in another view holder RecyclerView android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two View holders . On clicking a button in one view I want a text to get updated in another view of the Recycler.
It works fine with getRootview().
But on scrolling when the view gets hidden, recycler crashes (as getRootView no longer returns anything).
How can I implement this ?

ViewHolder1:

```
public static class CartHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView list_cart_header_textView_total; 
    private TextView list_cart_header_textView_title; 
}
```

ViewHolder2:

```
public class CartDBItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener { 
    private ImageView list_cart_product_imageView_add; 
}
```

onClick of list_cart_product_imageView_add:

```
CartHeader ch=new CartHeader(view.getRootView());
storeHeader=Double.parseDouble(ch.list_cart_header_textView_‌​total.getText().toSt‌​ring());
```

Comment: May you put some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists in Android use the Model-View-Controller paradigm.  The `RecyclerView` is the View, of course, and the adapter is the Model.

Within the Controller (onClick handler), when you want to change something in the View you change the Model then update the View.  So you change the text at its source in the adapter, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to let the `RecyclerView` know to refresh its views from the adapter.

You should only access view holders when creating their layouts or binding their data.